# How to set camel json Jackson options autoDiscoverObjectMapper

Tags: jackson, apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-jackson

I am using camel v3.14.10 with spring 5 and idk 8 no springboot app.

I would like `camel-jackson` configuration to pickup my custom ObjectMapper but following check prevents that in camel-jackson.jar codebase.

`AbstrackJacksonDataFormat` `doStart()` method checks for `isAutoDiscoverObjectMapper`

following [Json Jackson options](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/dataformats/json-jackson-dataformat.html) explains if I set isAutoDiscoverObjectMapper option to true it will pick my object mapper from camel context registry. how do I set`jackson.auto-discover-object-mapper=true` through java code instead of putting in application properties file.

help is appreciate.